# SCSS @import within @if project logic

Tags: sass, compass-sass, importerror

I want to generate various css files such as:

- global.css
- mobile.css
- tablet.css
- desktop.css
- mobile-forum.css
- table-forum.css

and etc.
I have such HTML code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-width: 450px)" href="assets/css/mobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 450px) and (max-width: 1024px)" href="assets/css/tablet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1264px)" href="assets/css/desktop.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-width: 1264px)" href="assets/css/widescreen.css">
```

So i created each *.scss with such content:

in desktop.scss

```
$mode: "desktop";
@import "main";
```

in _main.scss i created such variable:

```
$desktop: false;
@if $mode == 'desktop' {
$desktop: true;
}
```

So the problem is such. I whant to use _normilize.scss

```
@if $global {
    @import "parts/normalize";
}
```

But i have error here:

```
Syntax error: Import directives may not be used within control directives or mixins.
    on line 3 of /opt/code/host/resulinkpro/design/assets/sass/_main.scss
```

Compiling using **compass watch**

And my question are:

1. Can i make that work (other version of SCSS or COMPASS)?
2. If not can be any alternatives? The main idea contain logic in _main.scss and nested files, not in global.scss or mobile.scss (i just enable a mode there and nothing more)
3. Or LESS will be better for such task?

My main idea is to avoid unwanted media-queries, in this making .css smaller and then using javascript replace mode (currently using media attribute in  tag). Also use only necessary styles in browser.

Comment: You're not saving anything by doing this because *all* browsers download *all* CSS files, even if the media query conditions aren't met.

Comment: @cimmanon Yes i know. Can you watch at this in other point, after doing this i can load only necessary styles using PHP on server side (according to device - mobile or not) or JS on client side(depending on width). Also have various styles rules for various pages. It`s just a simply question, the main thing i want to use @import using @if condition.

Comment: Sass already told you the answer very clearly.  Browser sniffing is awful and you should feel bad for trying to do it.